# Knockout JS: Passing observable array as argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, arguments, observable

I have a 2d observable array called textFields:

```
var t1 = ko.observableArray([{val: 0}, {val:0}])
self.textFields = ko.observableArray([t1]);
```

And I have a function called solve that is supposed to take an argument:

```
self.solve = function(arr){
console.log(arr);
}
```

In my html, I have associated that function with a link click that passes textFields as an argument to solve:

```
<a id='solveBtn' href='#' data-bind='click: solve(textFields)'>Solve</a>
```

I thought I'd now get my textFields-array printed out. But instead, I get []. When I look at the variable in the debugger in Chrome, I also just see []. Why is that? Why is textFields not properly passed to solve?

EDIT:

I made the js now look like this:

```
self.solve = function(arr){
console.log(arr());
}
```

But know I want to pass this observable array to another function (which is supposed to make a 'normal' array out of it:

```
var normalize = function(arr){
    var retArr = [];
    console.log(arr().length);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var temp = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < arr()[i]().length; j++){
            temp.push(arr()[i]()[j].val);
        }
        console.log(temp);
        retArr.push(temp);
    }
    return retArr;
}
```

The console.log(arr()) gives me the following error: Message: object is not a function. When I treat arr as a normal array, the for-loop is never executed. I gues that's because arr[i] has length 0.

Thank you very much for your answers!

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this in markup to get array values in your solve method

```
<a id='solveBtn' data-bind='click: function(){solve(textFields())}'>Solve</a>
```

or modify your script as follows

```
self.solve = function(arr){
        console.log(arr());
}
```

Quick note : In your sample markup, you are setting a function with parameter to the click event. This will cause the function to get executed during page load. It is always safe to wrap it in a function block as below.

```
<a id='solveBtn' data-bind='click: function(){solve(textFields)}'>Solve</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your second suggestion and it now gives me a console output that looks like [function, function] which is a lot better I guess. When I take a closer look at this object in the debugger though, it looks very comlicated. But that may be due to knockout.

The more important problem is that I next want to pass arr to another function. That doesn't work. I edited the question to make clear what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure which part is confusing when you check the output in the console. The following code will print the results in the solve method, also passes the array to another method and print the results.

    self.solve = function(arr){
        for(var i=0;i<arr().length;i++){
            console.log(arr()[i].val);
            }
            
            newFunction(arr());
     } 
     
        function newFunction(arrParam){
        for(var i=0;i<arrParam.length;i++){
            console.log(arrParam[i].val);
            }
        }

Comment: Why is it possible to use arrParam.length whereas it is not possible to use arr.length but arr().length? Isn't the object passed the same as the original one?

Comment: I think I got it: It is because you pass arr(), not arr.

Comment: yes, that's correct. you are almost there. If you want to access the content of an observable, use parenthesis. Once you have got the value, treat it as a normal array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I know have a significantly better understanding of how knockout observables work as functions.